# Shell: check if no new line is added to file for 5 seconds

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that writes new lines to a local file called "log" line by line, I want to know when it stops writing to file.

I want to write another script to check if no new line is added to file "log" for 5 seconds, then I print on screen "finished".

How can I do this in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bash` word count tool, `wc` with flag for reading lines twice to achieve this:-

```
#!/bin/bash

initial=$(wc -l < log)     # first capture of the number of lines
sleep 5s                    # Sleep for 5s

later=$(wc -l < log)       # Second capture of the line count

((later - initial)) && echo "Writing to log pending" || echo "Writing to log finished"
```